# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\logins\home.php on line 10 Call Stack

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
 {
 header("Location: index.php");
 }
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

The error occurred after I introduced a trigger to my table suppliers and changed the user_id from int to varchar such that instead of being 1 or 3 now it is SUPL001, when a I log in with wrong credentials it accepts and displays the error above. The page does not echo the name of the user on the header [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwbFE.png)

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` function, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead !

Comment: You haven't wrapped your input in `'` as you need to do when you use varchar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1-to)

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION);` check what r u getting in session

Answer (score 1):

If your user id is string as you mentioned **"SUPL001"** than you need to use quotes around user id as:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."'");
```

**Side Note:**

Stop using `mysql_*` its deprecated and close in PHP 7, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: thank you devpro, the error is no  longer there... however it is not displaying the username as required

Comment: @musyimi: glad to help u,

Comment: @musyimi: if its work, than dont forget to accept the answer... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli, mysql_* has been decapitated.

Also, please make sure that you escape the user in the user session. (SQL injection)

```
session_start();

// --- new connect, would be in dbconnect.php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// ---



if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}


/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."'")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}



mysqli_close($link);
```